# OOP (Java) - Best way to generate object

Tags: java, oop

If I want to generate a Java instances of a simple object with random values.

For Example, For class  :

```
class Entity {
    int id;
}
```

I want to add generate function that initialize an new instance with random value for id .

What is the best OOP method? I thought about 2 options:

1. To create static method in Entity class:

   ```
   class Entity {
     int id;
     public static Entity generate(){
         Entity e = new Entity ();
         int rand = MathUtil.generateRandomInt(); // method in util class 
                    in the project.
         e.setId(rand )
         return e;
    }
   }
   ```
2. To Create EntityGenerator class:

   ```
    class EntityGenerator{
        public Entity generate(){
         Entity e = new Entity ();
         int rand = MathUtil.generateRandomInt(); // method in util class 
                    in the project.
         e.setId(rand);
         return e;
       }

   }
   ```

I hesitate what is the better option.

Comment: You would only really need the `EntityGenerator` if the construction of `Entity`s required other information. Then you could supply the information when you create a `EntityGenerator` (which would probably be considered a Factory object), then the `EntityGenerator` could pass that information to `generate` when needed. If you don't need to supply the same information on the creation of each Entity, I can't see a benefit to the second option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1 is better follow "effective in java joshua bloch". You can find it in the first chapter "Static factory". You also don't need new EntityGenerator to create an entity so it will save a memory.

```
class Entity {
  int id;
  public static Entity generate(){
      Entity e = new Entity ();
      int rand = MathUtil.generateRandomInt(); // method in util class 
                 in the project.
      e.setId(rand )
      return e;
 }
}
```

Comment: Following the JDK pattern, you'd have an `Entities` class for the static factories (cfg `ExecutorService`/`Executors`, `Collection`/`Collections` etc).

Answer (score 2):

You only need to create a object of your class. it will automatic populated with random number..

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Entity {

  private int id;

  public Entity() {
    id = new Random().nextInt(100000);//set the upper limit, it generated numbers between 0 and 99999
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Entity setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

}
```

Or you can make a static `Random()` object in class .

```
public class Entity {
  private static Random r = new Random();
  private int id;

  public Entity() {
    id = r.nextInt(100000);//set the upper limit, it generated numbers between 0 and 99999
  }

  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public Entity setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    return this;
  }

}
```

Hope it will Help.

Comment: @user2840073 mark it an answer. if it solve your problem . thanks

Comment: Why do you return Entity in the setter?

Comment: Actually i use the builder pattern.

Comment: It will help to create empty object and set properties with sequence of instructions with the dot. Like object.setId(1).setName(“khalid”).setAge(25); rather than making a parameterized constructor.

Comment: That's ok then, actually I suspected :), but mentioning it makes it more clear.

Comment: Thanks Khalid Shah! My question was more general, theoretical, no matter the details of the random. How better to do generator - in the class itself or in separate class.

Answer (score 0):

Option 2:
separated `EntityGenerator` class (actually it is a Factory) is also applicable, but only with some restrictions either

- `public Entity generate()` will be static as `public static Entity generate()`.
- or you have to use `EntityGenerator` as singleton (i.e. only one instance of it will be created and used across your program).

Difference will be only of what pattern is preferable for you 
(I assume you may have more than one "Entity" kind classes.)

- have static `generate` method in each and every class for its own
- centralized factory to create all kind of them in special `EntityGenerator` class.